# Add to exception web route in laravel when 1 parameter missing

Tags: laravel

I have problem with laravel framework where i have two parameters in web route and exact value to find something in my database. When i remove one character, there is error.

Route is:

```
Route::get('/serije/prikaz/{id}/{naziv}', 'SerijeController@prikaz')->where(['id' => '[0-9]+', 'naziv' => '^[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$']);
```

Controller is:

```
public function prikaz($id, $naziv)
    {
        $serija = DB::table('serije')
            ->where(
                [
                    ['id', '=', $id],
                    ['slug', '=', $naziv],
                ]
            )
            ->first();
return view('serije.prikaz', ['serija' => $serija,);
}
```

So my url is like:
http://localhost/serije/prikaz/418/elite

ID=418
slug=elite

That is in database, when i remove only one character, like
http://localhost/serije/prikaz/418/elit

There is error

```
ErrorException
Trying to get property 'naziv' of non-object
http://localhost/serije/prikaz/418/elit
```

How can i create custom error message like "There is no data for that", or "You make wrong url".

Thanks.

Comment: you should check `@if($serija == null)` in your blade view

Comment: Or you could replace `->first()` with `->firstOrFail()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add some messaging to your controller:

```
public function prikaz($id, $naziv)
{
    $serija = DB::table('serije')
        ->where(
            [
                ['id', '=', $id],
                ['slug', '=', $naziv],
            ]
        )
        ->first();
    $message = $serija ? '': 'There is no data for that';

    return view('serije.prikaz', compact('serija', 'message'));
}
```

Then check to make sure `$serija` is not null in your view and display the message if it is.

Answer (score 1):

[Laravel Parameter Validation Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#manually-creating-validators)

Import Class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
```

Within Function:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'id' => 'required',
    'naviz' => 'required'
]);

if($validator->fails()) {
    $errors = $validator->errors();
    return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'data' => null, 'message' => $errors], 422);
}
```